# What's a Good Database ERD Tool for Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, erd

I've recently switched to Linux on my work machine and, new to the Linux desktop environment, I'd like to find a decent ERD tool for database design.  Booting back into my Windows partition every time I need to create a diagram is going to get unpleasant quickly.  I looked at Dia, but didn't see any DB tools - only UML, networking, etc.

Anyone have any recommendations?  For what it's worth, I'm using Ubuntu (Hardy Heron).

Thanks.

Comment: GenMyModel (https://www.genmymodel.com) now supports database modeling. It is online and runs perfectly on linux.

Comment: https://drawerd.com is a online erd tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a stop gap, I've installed DBDesigner via Wine (I should have just done that first) since that's what my Windows developers are using, but will look at both of these as well.  The Eclipse plugin would be ideal if it's decent.

Thanks.

Comment: DBDesigner is no longer under active development. MySQL Workbench (mentioned elsewhere among the answers) is laid out to be its successor. It's in Beta right now, and I think you should keep an eye on it.

Comment: This accepted answer is somehow misleading...

Answer (score 15):

MySQL just officially released the alpha of "MySQL Workbech for linux":

See the announcement here:
[MySQL Workbench 5.1 Alpha for Linux available](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/?p=153).

Comment: It's awesome, but many of features are buggy :(

Comment: version 6.3 fixes many things, but it is for 64 bit only

Answer (score 5):

I'd definitely recommend [Gliffy.com](http://www.gliffy.com/) for simple ER diagrams; it's an online flash-based tool. I wrote a small [review](http://www.davedevelopment.co.uk/2008/08/11/review-gliffycom/) of it a week ago.

Answer (score 3):

For a generic (vendor independent) tool, you can try dia (I prefer the dia-gnome package).
There are also some plugins for generating the SQL files.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL Workbench is available on MacOS, Fedora, Ubuntu, Windows.

WB 5.1 is focused on Data Modeling (replacing Mike Zinner’s popular DBDesigner product).

WB 5.2 (coming April 2009) will include a ground up rewrite of the MySQL Query Browser.

http://forums.mysql.com/index.php?151

Comment: Wait what. I didn't know organizations can answer like this...

Answer (score 2):

Check out SQL Developer: [http://sqldeveloper.solyp.com/download/index.html]

Answer (score 2):

Mmm I think the Linux version of MySQL Workbench is out for download at:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,56274,56274#msg-56274

You can see the pre-release announcement here:
http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/?p=138

They are still in alpha, but judging from the windows version this is gonna be "THE" ERD tool.

PD: For the ubuntu part, you are in luck, they say that ubuntu is "our Linux distro of choice".

Answer (score 2):

Look at Oracle JDeveloper (freeware). It is pure Java, so it will run on any platform. It will work against any database that you can connect to via JDBC. It builds database diagrams (and lots of other diagrams - it happens to be a complete Java IDE).

It works with a concept of "offline database objects" stored in XML files. So if you have existing database objects, you start by capturing them into JDeveloper and then build your diagram. If you make changes to your offline objects, you can "reconcile" them back into your database, either as new objects (DROP-REPLACE) or as modifications (ALTER).

Download at http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/jdev/index.html

Answer (score 1):

No recommendations as such, but,

You might want to broaden your search to Eclipse plugins such as http://eclipse-erd.sourceforge.net/.

Apart from that there are various ERD tools you have to pay for like [Data Architect](http://www.thekompany.com/products/dataarchitect/).

Answer (score 1):

I had bad experience with Workbench on Linux in the past and wish it got better now.

I am quite happy with [SchemaBank](http://schemabank.com) these days 'cause they are purely web-based. You drop them a few bucks every month and they host your diagram for private / public sharing. Usual stuff like forward / reverse engineering, alter scripts, etc are all supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ORM Designer http://www.orm-designer.com 
Tool is similar to DBDesigner, but has much more functions and is under everyday development.

Comment: ORM Designer just received large upgrade and it is now available under the name Skipper: http://www.skipper18.com

Answer (score -4):

You can try Base from [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/features/base/). It can connect to any database and you can easily create, design and write queries using visual wizards and tools.

Comment: I have used Base to design and ER model, and it is very easy and good for the thing i needed. Can also be used to generate queries, forms and reports which can be used as models or even used as standalone DB.